# How to change the "remember-me" Laravel cookie lifetime?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, cookies, remember-me

I use the built-in "Remember me" functionnality of Laravel 5.8. I checked the cookies and saw the `remember-me` cookie expires in about 5 years. That is way to long and I would like to shorten it. As Laravel automaticly creates the cookie, I don't have the hand on it. How can I do this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The remember me duration can be overridden by overriding the `AuthenticatesUsers` trait. You could add the following code to `LoginController` that overrides the trait in the following controller:

```
protected function sendLoginResponse(Request $request)
{
    $customRememberMeTimeInMinutes = 10;
    $rememberTokenCookieKey = Auth::getRecallerName();
    Cookie::queue($rememberTokenCookieKey, Cookie::get($rememberTokenCookieKey), $customRememberMeTimeInMinutes);

    $request->session()->regenerate();

    $this->clearLoginAttempts($request);

    return $this->authenticated($request, $this->guard()->user())
            ?: redirect()->intended($this->redirectPath());
}
```

An alternative is to invalidate the remember me session by setting the `remember_token` in the `users` table to an empty value. 
Example:

```
$user = Auth::user();
$user->remember_token = null;
$user->save();
```

Comment: I must admit I do not really understand how this works, but it works, so thanks ! I will try to understand when getting into cookies more deeply.

Answer (score 1):

This is (at time of writing) so much easier with Laravel 8 (and likely earlier).

Just add the key `remember` to the appropiate guard in your `config/auth.php` file. In this example I have a custom guard called `customGuard`

```php
'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],

        'customGuard' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
            'remember' => "10080" //Number of minutes the "remember me" option works for.
        ],

        'api' => [
            'driver' => 'token',
            'provider' => 'users',
            'hash' => false,
        ],
    ],
```

Comment: This answer works from 8.65.0 and up : https://github.com/laravel/framework/releases/tag/v8.65.0

Answer (score 1):

You can set the remember me cookie duration by adding `'remember' => 43800` in the config in `config/auth.php`

Just change:

```
'guards' => [
    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],
],
```

to:

```
'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
            'remember' => 43800 // Set remember me duration here (minutes)
        ],
    ],
```

Note: The 'remember' key is a mandatory keyword, because it will be read by laravel in [`Illuminate\Auth\AuthManager`](https://laravel.com/api/9.x/Illuminate/Auth/AuthManager.html) namespace